# How to simply read from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I have **appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionString": "Server=...;Database=...;Trusted_Connection=True;"

}
```

and **Database** class

```
public class Database : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=...;Database=...;Trusted_Connection=True;");

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Material>().ToTable("vw_Material", schema: "query");
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Material> Material { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is, how to replace this line

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=...;Database=...;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

with value from appsettings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DI for this purpose. To do that you need to register Configuration in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...    
   services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
}
```

Then you can inject it to Database constructor:

```
private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

public Database(IConfiguration config) 
{
    configuration = config;
}
```

and access it on configuring:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
```

Another option is to use Options pattern. In this case you have to create a class with the property which you need:

```
public class ConnectionStringConfig
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Register it on Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...    
   services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);
}
```

Inject to Database constructor:

```
private readonly ConnectionStringConfig configuration;

public Database(IOptions<ConnectionStringConfig> config) 
{
    configuration = config.Value;
}
```

and access it on configuring:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(configuration.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried first solution and it works, I only needed to use `configuration["ConnectionString"]` except of `configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")` to get it working.